# Change image automatically in drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to create a component that displays images and keeps it changing automatically every few seconds. This component is at the top of the site that was created with drupal. How can I do this in drupal?

Is it possible to create pages in drupal that uses html and javascript? Or drupal just use php?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 uses twig as a template engine. Drupal 7 uses php.

Usually (in drupal 8) you can add new CSS/JS files inside your theme in a file called 'yourthemename'.libraries.yml

You can create a multiple image field in sitebuilder and then use a carousel like owl or slick to achieve the image swipe.

check this link (libraries)

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

About twig templates

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates

PS: Drupal 8 has a contrib module called Slick. Check here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/slick